# How to image set my layout?

Tags: css, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am not frontend developer. I am using bootstrap my current code like below image:

[image]

```
 <div class="panel-body">

                        <form action="">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                   <div class=" row">
                                <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputDefault">Full Name</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='Profile.full_name ' name='full_name' readonly>
                                </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                  <div class=" row">
                                <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputDefault">Company Name</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault" readonly ng-model='Profile.company_name ' name='company_name'>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                  <div class=" row">
                                <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputDefault">Mobile Number</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault" readonly  ng-model='Profile.mobile_number ' name='mobile_number'>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class=" col-xs">
                        <img src="\images\blank.jpg" alt="\images\blank.jpg" >
                          </div>
                            </form>
                                </div>
```

I want my image looks like this :

[image]

Comment: And where's your css?

Comment: using default css bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="panel-body">



                       <div class="col-md-8">

                        <form action="">
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <div class=" row">
                                <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputDefault">Full Name</label>
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='Profile.full_name ' name='full_name' readonly>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>

                                  <div class="form-group ">
                                   <div class="row">
                                <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Email</label>
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <input type="text" ng-model='Profile.email'  id="email"  name='email' readonly class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" aria-invalid="false">
                                </div>
                                  </div>
                                    </div>


                            </form>
                            </div>

                               <div class="col-md-4">

                       <img src="\images\blank.jpg" alt="\images\blank.jpg" >
                               </div>
```

Comment: try using col-xs instead of md